# gcc: templated base class doesn't compile

Tags: c++, gcc

Why this code compiles succesfully in VS13 and fails to compile by gcc?

```
template <typename T>    
class Base
{
protected:
    typedef std::map<T, double> MyMap;
    MyMap m_map;

public:
    void func(const T& key)
    {
        typename MyMap::iterator it = m_map.find(key);
        if(it != m_map.end()) {
            // ....
        }
    }
};

class Inherited1 : public Base <char>
{ };
class Inherited2 : public Base <int>
{ };
```

It results in following errors (gcc 4.1.2)

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void Base<T>::func(const T&)’:
test.cpp:16: error: expected `;' before ‘it’
test.cpp:17: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
```

**EDIT1:**
Thanks for replies. Tried using keyword `typename` as juanchopanza suggested, now I got this errors:

```
/tmp/ccotJWFl.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, double> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, double> >*, unsigned long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKidEEE10deallocateEPS5_m[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, double> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, double> >*, unsigned long)]+0x19): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccotJWFl.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<char const, double> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<char const, double> >*, unsigned long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKcdEEE10deallocateEPS5_m[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<char const, double> > >::deallocate(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<char const, double> >*, unsigned long)]+0x19): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccotJWFl.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
```

**EDIT2:**
This whole stuff becomes even more ridiculous - it results in the above mentioned errors if I use `gcc test.cpp` compiles successfully if I write `g++ test.cpp`

Comment: You're missing a `typename`: `typename MyMap::iterator it = ...`

Comment: try to get a compiler with better error messages, either newer version of GCC or clang.

Comment: 4.1.2? The museum of software palaeontology may have a claim on this fossil.

Comment: because VS13 was wrong to compile your faulty code.

Comment: @n.m.: I wish, we still have some software compiled with 3.4.2 at work; migration to 4.3.2 was already ongoing when I joined 7 years ago... but nobody bothers about the stuff that is already working (not worth it).

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for reply. Sadly that won't work

Comment: @VramVardanian: The new error seems to suggest you're not linking with the C++ runtime library. Make sure you link using `g++` not `gcc`.

Comment: @VramVardanian: Re edit 2: `gcc` is the C compiler, which is why it fails to link a C++ program. You need `g++` to link with the correct language's runtime libraries.